# How do i run same script over and over, with delay between each run?

Tags: javascript, shell

in order to run a same script multiple times, i currently use `;`

For example, i will run something like this

`node RocketLaunch.js;node RocketLaunch.js;node RocketLaunch.js`

This works great and run my script 3 times back to back. I am wondering is there an easy way i can run these 3 with gap of 1 hour?

**Edit** - Thank you for the responses, i am new to learning programming so apologize for posting this in JS, since it seems like a non JS question.

**More information** - The way i want to intend to use it, run this script every 1 hour for lets say 20 hours/times. The entire job takes around 5 minutes after i run the script and i want it to run every hour and do that 5 minutes job.

So perhaps run a command at Bash level, where i can type it 20 times with a delay of an hour. It runs every hour for 20 hours, then i can do the whole thing again.

Comment: Put `sleep 3600` between them.

Comment: That's not really a JavaScript question (though of course you could also implement the timeout in JavaScript). https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html

Comment: And if you want to run it every hour, use `cron`.

Comment: If you are using it in Cloud. then use the Cloud Functions Schedule. or Cron Jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated answer to your question

Now just run `node RocketLaunch.js 1 20` This is the command to tell the script to run every 1 hour for the next 20 hours.

```html
const rockets = {
    launched: () => {
        //your job
        console.log("I'm A Rocket");
    }
};
var arg = process.argv;
const times = Number(arg.slice(2)[1]);
const hours = Number(arg.slice(2)[0])  * 3600000; // to make the hour;

 function launch() {
    var x = 1
    //kick off rockets at script start
    rockets.launched();
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        rockets.launched();
        x++
        if (x === times) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, hours) //1000 ms = 1 second
}

launch();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I typically do this in bash:

```
for x in {1..3};
do
node RocketLaunch.js
sleep 3600
done
```

The `{1..3}` tells the for loop to do this 3 times, and the sleep function takes the number of seconds as its argument. (3600 = 60 seconds * 60 minutes)